# Ionic/Cordova - Why are node_modules ignored while committing to git?

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, node-modules

First of all, pardon my ignorance of ionic/cordova framework.

`node_modules` directory is generated by `ionic start` command. If someone clones my repo hosted on `bitbucket`, they will be devoid of `node_modules` directory since they haven't used `ionic start` command and git ignored it. Wouldn't it be causing any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because libraries in node_modules directory to be saved in packege.json and they have large size, too many files. So, when you commited to git, they were ignored.

Cheer!

Comment: But then, why node_modules directory is generated in the first place? Isn't it easier to generate package.json directly? Or is the content of package.json dependant on the  components of node_modules that we use in  the project? If it is so, and if the other person wants to contribute some changes, will it require the node_modules directory in his local repo to create the new package.json ?